# WPF 4.0 Databinding the ContextMenu on the DataGrid

Tags: wpf, data-binding, datagrid, contextmenu

I'm having a hell of a time trying to dynamically bind the ContextMenu on a DataGrid. The DataGrid is bound to a list of objects which works great:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding DataGridItems}">
```

For each of the DataGridItem objects I have a list of MenuItems exposed on a property which I would like to use to bind to the ContextMenu.
I tried the below but I think I’m missing something:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding DataGridItems}">
     <DataGrid.ContextMenu>
          <ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding ContextMenuItems}" >
               <MenuItem Header="{Binding Name}" Command="{Binding OnClick}"></MenuItem>
          </ContextMenu>
     </DataGrid.ContextMenu>
 <DataGrid>
```

```
public class DataGridItem
{
    public ObservableCollection<ContextMenuItem> ContextMenuItems
    {
        get { return _contextMenuItems; }
    }
}
```

Any help or guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: Probably just a typo, but your class that represents a single item is called "DataGridItems"?  Also, posting more complete code would probably make it easier to troubleshoot.

Comment: You're correct the class name should have been DataGridItem. I will update.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is how I ended up solving it:

```
<StackPanel.ContextMenu>
<ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding ContextMenu}">
    <ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
            <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding OnClick}" />
            <Setter Property="Icon">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <Image Source="{Binding ImageName}"></Image>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ContextMenu:ContextMenuItem}" ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItems}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>
</ContextMenu>
```

Comment: This almost worked for me, but I needed to replace the `<Setter Property="Icon"> block with `<Setter Property="Icon" Value="{Binding ImageName}" />` instead

Answer (score 3):

I believe [this tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/ContextMenuDataContext.aspx) describes your issue, but effectively you'd have to do:

```
<ContextMenu DataContext="{Binding PlacementTarget.DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
    ItemsSource="{Binding ContextMenuItems}" />
```